# Set list to g:paginate - grails

Tags: grails

guys!

I am studiyng the framework grails and noticed that by default the tag  only works if the variable is in default "${propertName}List". If I change the name of the list how show the code below, the paginate not work.

```
respond list: Categoria.list(params), model:[categoriaCount: Categoria.count()]
```

There are a way of set the name of the list?

Comment: No... Something is not right. I'm certain paginate can accept the name you want. What does your `g:paginate` code look like?

Comment: Hi! The code is <g:paginate total="${categoriaCount ?: 0}" />

Comment: I changed the method index and see that the paginate works. The code it looked like this `[list: Categoria.list(params), categoriaCount: Categoria.count()]`.

What could it be?